# Interpret the output of lscpu

Tags: lscpu

Where I work, I have access to a cluster. I logged in into one node and did "lscpu".

Here's the output:

[image]

Now I am very confused. If I google the CPU: `Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2699 v4`: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/91317/intel-xeon-processor-e52699-v4-55m-cache-2-20-ghz/specifications.html

It says the CPU has 22 cores and 44 threads. So does this node of the server has 1 or 2 of these chips?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here using a [code block] for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You’re in a virtual machine (managed by a VMware product) with 46 vCPUs, which show up as 46 sockets hosting single-core, single-thread CPUs. The underlying platform presumably has more threads, using two sockets (the maximum supported by E5-2xxx CPUs).